# Error when trying to concatenate lists with pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation, tabula-py

I have a folder with 100 PDF files. Page 1 of all PDF files contains a table that I am extracting. Then I am concatenating all the tables into a dataframe and writing as a CSV file. However, I am getting error while concatenating.

```py
import os

import camelot
import pandas as pd
import PyPDF2
import tabula

# Set the directory path where the PDF files are located
dir_path = "my/path/"

# Create an empty list to store the tables
tables = []

# Loop through each file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(dir_path):
    # Check if the file is a PDF file
    if filename.endswith(".pdf"):
        # Open the PDF file
        with open(os.path.join(dir_path, filename), "rb") as pdf_file:
            # Create a PDF reader object
            pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)

            # Get the first page of the PDF file
            page = pdf_reader.getPage(0)

            # Extract the table from the first page using tabula-py
            table = tabula.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages=1, pandas_options={"header": True})
            print(table)

            # Append the table to the tables list
            tables.append(table)

# Concatenate all tables into a single DataFrame
df = pd.concat(tables)

# Write the DataFrame to a CSV file
df.to_csv("Output.csv", index=False)
```

> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: Convert them to dataframes: `tables.append(pd.DataFrame(table))`

Comment: ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 3, 6)

Answer (score 0):

[tabula.read_pdf](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html#tabula.io.read_pdf) returns a list of dataframes, so in your code, `tables` contains a list of lists of dataframes.

For Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to work, you have to flatten `tables` first, like this:

```py
df = pd.concat([table for sub_list in tables for table in sub_list])
```

Don't forget to set `output_format="dataframe"` when calling `tabula.read_pdf`.